# Unable to get relative path from root to img src in rails application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, image, file-upload

I have a small rails application in which if the environment is development, I am storing images locally. I can see that the image is successfully being uploaded but for some reason when I use the relative path of that image in the src attribute of my img tag, the image breaks and shows nothing.

The file I upload is stored in directory folder as below

```
       projectName
        -tmp
         -uploads
           -files
             -file
              -50
                -testImage.png
```

There are several folders in the project where tmp is one of those folders. Now I want to access the testImage in the src attribute of img tag. I have tried

```
        <img src="/uploads/files/file/50/testImage.png" />
```

Also,

```
        <img src="/tmp/uploads/files/file/50/testImage.png" />
```

But in both cases I get the image as nil.

[image]

Domain is localhost:3000 and img tag resides in a js file.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What error do you see in the dev tools console? Or in the rails server output?

Comment: No errors there